# access field of foregin key in django model function

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have the following `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I need to add a function `fullName(self)` that will return a string, the person's name + space + the person's father name. What is the correct syntax to do this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def fullName(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.father.name
```

**pylint** says: instance of 'ForeginKey' has no 'name' member

Comment: Have you got *error* or just warning?

Comment: pylint says:instance of 'ForeginKey' has no 'name' member...
The makemigrate and then migrate commands works fine but the app crashes with many errors when I try to add a record from the admin panel